# Forcing Spring to call subclass for one method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, annotations, spring-annotations

New to spring magic, hoping spring magic can solve my dilemma.

My groovy/spring app uses a jar to handle logging in. I want to override a method in the jar to do some custom processing during the log in process (post login).

The class in the jar looks like this:

```
@Component
class Processor extends GenericProcessor {
    @Override
    ProcessedRequest handle(Request request) {
        // do things
       return processRequest(request)
    }

    //Do nothing method method I want to override
    ProcessedRequest processRequest(request) {
        return request
    }
}
```

In my application, I have subclass that extends the jar class:

```
class MyProcessor extends Processor {

    @Override
    ProcessedRequest processRequest(request) {
        //do custom processing 
       return request
    }
}
```

I tried making `MyProcessor` an `@Component`, but the `Processor` class just calls its own `processRequest` method instead of the `processRequest` method in `myProcessor`.
Is there something I can do with Spring to say "Whenever `myProcessor` exists, use it instead of `Processor`" through some combination of @Component/@Bean/@Qualifier?

Other notes:
Processor in the jar is called within the jar, so it isn't easy to replace the call location with `myProcessor`
I do have access to change the jar source code, though I would rather not, as its a shared jar.

Answer (score -1):

as a suggestion, try to put `@Primary` under your class `MyProcessor`. use `@Primary` to give higher preference to a bean when there are multiple beans of the same type

```
@Component
@Primary
class myProcessor extends Processor {
    ...
}
```